# How to combine separate Date and Time columns into DateTime?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a customer database which include LMD(Last Modified Date) data type is date and LMT(Last Modified Time) data type is int. I need to create a datetime from this LMD and LMT column. Here are the rows,

```
LMD          LMT
2014-09-03  172351
```

Comment: Is that read as 17:23:51? hh:mm:ss?

Comment: Not sure but I think so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use divsion and modulo to extract  the needed parts for DATEADD

```
declare @datefield date
declare @timefield int

set @datefield='20140910'
set @timefield=121314

Select CAST(@datefield AS DATETIME) + DATEADD(HOUR,@timefield/10000,0) + DATEADD(MINUTE,@timefield/100 % 100,0)+ DATEADD(SECOND,@timefield % 100,0)


Select CAST(LMD AS datetime) + DATEADD(HOUR,LMT/10000,0) + DATEADD(MINUTE,LMT/100 % 100,0)+ DATEADD(SECOND,LMT % 100,0), LMT, LMD
FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 1):

This works using `TIMEFROMPARTS` and adding it to the date.

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3dc52/1)**

```
select cast(LMD as datetime) + cast(timefromparts(substring(cast(lmt as varchar), 1, 2), substring(cast(lmt as varchar), 3, 2), substring(cast(lmt as varchar), 5, 2),0,0) as datetime)
from yourTable
```

Answer (score 1):

If LMD is a date and LMT is an int:

```
SELECT 
    DATETIMEFROMPARTS(
        YEAR(LMD), 
        MONTH(LMD), 
        DAY(LMD), 
        (LMT / 10000) % 100, 
        (LMT / 100) % 100, 
        LMT % 100, 0
    )
```

Comment: Getting `Argument data type int is invalid for argument 1 of substring function.`